# Getting This page isn’t working redirected you too many times error when trying to redirect to login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple application controller, and I puzzled by its behavior. It just won't let me connect to a login page

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :do_atthestart

  protected
    def do_atthestart
       redirect_to login_path
    end
end
```

Once the "redirect_to login_path" is hit, I get the error on a browser that says

> This page isn’t working redirected you too many times

And on the log I get the following information

> Started GET "/login" for ..................................
> Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML Redirected to
> http://127.0.0.1:3000/login Filter chain halted as :do_atthestart
> rendered or redirected Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms
> | Allocations: 282)

Does anyone have any idea how to move forward beyond it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: well you have that in the application controller so it will redirect to the login page, which then redirects to the login page, so on and so on.   You need to change that up so it doesn't redirect when it hits the sessions new method it looks like.  Generate the sessions controller or if you have one, skip the before action in there for that method.  although it will still redirect all the time so you need to add a user check too to see if the user is logged in as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `before_action` is creating an endless loop.

It applies to any action in any controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`, including `SessionsController#new`. The callback redirects to that action, which then calls the callback, which redirects to that action, and so on.

One technique would be to load the `before_action` in each controller. Then, in your sessions controller, you could except the function from the callback:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :do_atthestart, except: :new
end
```